Negative Semi-Definiteness of the Slutsky Matrix
I am following the famous book MWG to study microeconomics. It is stated in Section 2.F. that if a differentiable demand function $x(p,w):\mathbb{R}^n_+\times \mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies Walras' law, homogeneity of degree zero, and the weak axiom, then the Slutsky matrix
$$S(p,w)=D_px(p,w)+D_wx(p,w)x(p,w)^t$$
is negative semi-definite. Here's the argument presented in the book:
By the compensated law of demand, we have its differential analogue:
$$dp\cdot dx\leq 0$$
By using chain rule, we have
\begin{align*}
dx&=D_px(p,w)dp+D_wx(p,w)dw\\
&=D_px(p,w)dp+D_wx(p,w)x(p,w)\cdot dp\\
dp[D_px(p,w)dp+D_wx(p,w)x(p,w)^t]dp&=dp\cdot dx\leq 0
\end{align*}
I understand this argument, but I don't think it is rigorous enough. I think a rigorous proof should appeal to the mean value theorem (in several variables), which implies that for any $p,p'\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists some $c\in [0,1]$ such that
\begin{align*}
z&:=(1-c)p+cp'\\
w'&:=p'\cdot x(p,w)\\
x(p',w')-x(p,w)&=x(p',w+(p'-p)\cdot x(p,w))-x(p,w)\\
&=D_px(z,w+(z-p)\cdot x(p,w))\cdot (p'-p)\\
&+D_wx(z,w+(z-p)\cdot x(p,w))x(p,w)\cdot (p'-p)
\end{align*}
But how should I proceed?
